# Why is the query returning only one set of data?

Tags: php, mysql

The problem I have is when I echo or print the following variables, the data I receive is that of the last business listed in my table only.

At present no matter the listing I click I get the same set of data for the last business returned.

As you can see in the below code I am passing the business_name from the clicked listing to be used in my query to find the relevant business profile information.

```
$business_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['business_name']);

$query = "SELECT
business_id,
category,
years_recommended,
profile_size,
business_name,
established,
employees,
service,
strengths,
ideal_for,
reassurance

FROM
business_data

WHERE
business_name = '$business_name'

AND
profile_size = 'A'

OR
profile_size = 'B'

OR
profile_size = 'C'

OR
profile_size = 'D'

OR
profile_size = 'E'";

$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc)
or die (mysql_error($dbc));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$business_id = $row["business_id"];
$profile_size = $row["profile_size"];
$category = $row["category"];
$years = $row["years_recommended"];
$established = $row["established"];
$employees = $row["employees"];
$service = $row["service"];
$strengths = $row["strengths"];
$ideal_for = $row["ideal_for"];
$reassurance = $row["reassurance"];
}

echo...
```

If you need more information please let me know.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Down votes a bit harsh. Its not like I have put in no effort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `echo` call is outside the fetch loop, so you'll only see the last result even though the others were returned.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

  $business_id = $row["business_id"];
  $profile_size = $row["profile_size"];
  $category = $row["category"];
  $years = $row["years_recommended"];
  $established = $row["established"];
  $employees = $row["employees"];
  $service = $row["service"];
  $strengths = $row["strengths"];
  $ideal_for = $row["ideal_for"];
  $reassurance = $row["reassurance"];

  // Echo **inside** the loop
  echo...
}
```

If you wish, you can store all the results in a large array, which can then be used anywhere subsequently in your script, as many times as needed:

```
// Array for all results
$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  // Append each row fetched onto the big array
  $results[] = $row;
}
// Now use it as needed:
foreach ($results as $r) {
  echo $r['profile_size'];
  print_r($r);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response. Is there any reason why I am getting a syntax error in komodo edit eg. a red underline when I move my curly braces after the echo.

Comment: @RichardBell If there is nothing after your `echo` call, and it's only `echo..` as above, that's a syntax error. If you use a real statement `echo $row['profile_size'];` there should be no error.

Comment: Ok. Having implemented `echo $row['profile_size'];` the variable contains all of the profile sizes rather than just the targeted one. I need to look at this further I think. There should only be one result where `business_name` matches a `profile_size`. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

your echo should be inside the loop